# Scanning multiple stored papers for words and save their occurrence (1 or 0) into a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file, for-loop, path

I am currently working on a first Python project and I am stuck in this step. I have a list of words (variable = wordlist) and files/papers stored in the path. The result should now show a matrix with columns = name of the paper and rows = words. If the word appears in the text, I want to get a '1' and if not a '0'.

Here's my Code:

```py
filelists = os.listdir("Path")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[filelists],index=[wordlist])

for docPath in filelists:
    doc = io.open("Path" + '\\' + docPath, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
    file_content = doc.read()
    for word in wordlist:
        if word in file_content:
            df = df.append({'filelists': 1}, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            df = df.append({'filelists': 0}, ignore_index=True)
    doc.close()
    print(df)
```

When I'm running the code I get **TypeError: Expected tuple, got str**.

If I then put the value 1 and 0 in tuple() it solves this error.

```
if word in file_content:
    df = df.append({'filelists': tuple(1)}, ignore_index=True)
else:
    df = df.append({'filelists': tuple(0)}, ignore_index=True)
```

However, I now receive the following error.

**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

Can anyone here help me? As you may see, I am new to the coding, so please excuse me if I did something completely wrong in the code.

Comment: In 1st snippet, you're using `for word in wordlist:`, but in 2nd snippet, you're using `if Feature in file_content:`. Which one is correct?

Comment: I'm sorry the first one...I forgot to edit it...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in your code

```
filelists = os.listdir("Path")
```

in this, the variable `filelists` will be a list, say `['A', 'B']`. You need to  use `filelists` instead of `[filelists]` when creating a Dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=filelists, index=wordlist)
df = df.append({'A':1, 'B':1}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes this was surely a first error:). But now I'm getting many NaN's and only a few 0 and 1...